# How can i render objects in html through django templating via primary key?

Tags: django

i have a problem in searching articles on my home page. the problem is that when i enter a query in a search bar , the error  "Reverse for 'blog_detail/' not found. 'blog_detail/' is not a valid view function or pattern name." appears.

**code**

**homepage from where i search a query**

```
<form method="get" action={% url 'search' %} class="">
<!--        <form method="get" action="{% url 'search' %} class="">-->
  <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control bg-dark text-white" placeholder="Search Articles" aria-label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="basic-addon2">
  <div class="input-group-append bg-dark">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-primary bg-danger text-white" type="submit" >Search </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**search.html**

The action of the form sends query to this page

```
<div class="row">

    {% for item in post %}

          <div class="card my-3 text-white bg-dark mb-3" style="width: 18rem;">

            <img src="/media/{{item.thumbnail}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">{{item.title}}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">{{item.intro}}</p>
              <a href="{% url 'blog_detail/' id=item.post_id %}" class="btn btn-primary">read more...</a>

            </div>
          </div>

    {% if forloop.counter|divisibleby:5 %}
    </div>
    {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
</div>
```

this (`href="{% url 'blog_detail/' id=item.post_id %}"`) is giving an error saying (NoReverseMatch at /search/)

in the urls.py the route for blog_detail is : `path("blog_detail/<int:id>", views.blog_detail, name = "blog")`,

and for search route is : path("search/", views.search, name="search"),

in the models the primary key is set as post_id : post_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

i hope this information is enough....!

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of the [**`{% url … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) is the *name* of the path. So you should write this as:

```
href="{% url 'blog' id=item.post_id %}"
```

since in your `urlpatterns`, you wrote:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # …
    path("blog_detail/<int:id>", views.blog_detail, name="blog"),
    # …
]
```

Comment: you mean this:  name = "blog"?

Comment: @cyber_fish: you defined the name of the view as `name="blog"`, hence it means that in your `{% url ... %}` template tag, you should write `{% url 'blog' id=item.post_id %}`.